# How to make Visual Studio editor stop scrolling past bottom of a file?

Tags: visual-studio, editor

In the Visual Studio **editor** when you pull the **scroll bar** down to the bottom of the file, all you see is a **blank page**, since the text has scrolled up past the **top** of the text editor window. This makes scrolling to the bottom **difficult** because you can't just pull the scroll bar quickly all the way down but have to *carefully* position the cursor so you can still see your code.

**How can I make it so that, as in NotePad, when I pull the scroll bar down to the bottom of the file, I see the bottom of the file?**

Comment: Is this really a programming related technical question?

Comment: Perhaps it belongs on superuser, but it is something, if solved, would make my programming happier.

Comment: imho, it belongs here. for example, if somebody asked the same question about vim, nobody would complain.

Comment: on the other side, this realy is one of those "who cares" editor preferences, so ...

Comment: I can think of at least a 100 "who cares" options I'd gladly give up in VS to have this option.  I think Adobe and MS both could benefit from a nice feature diet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to use the keyboard instead, pressing `Ctrl+End` will achieve what you want.

Comment: yes, I've noticed that: it is odd that some editors (VisualStudio, PSPad) show the blank page below the text yet others show the text at the bottom of the file (NotePad, EditPad, NotePad++). What were the UX designers thinking for those editors which show a blank page, how would that be desirable?

Comment: I think the idea is to let you take any line of text and put it at the top of the editor window.

Answer (score 238):

There is a configuration option provided in VSCode for the functionality you specified. To enable it, go to File -> Preferences -> user settings

On the right side of the editor in settings.json paste the below line at the bottom (before closing bracket), save and close.

```
"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false
```

This will prevent the editor from scrolling beyond the last line.

Comment: This question is about the Visual Studio editor. VSCode is a different application.

Comment: This is a good answer but it answers different question. Answer relates to VS Code rather than Visual Studio. Someone has to manage in.

Comment: I needed exactly this as this behavior in VSCode was driving me nuts. Thank you, @Dani Akash

Answer (score 8):

Inside of VS Code, Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, and search for "Scroll Beyond Last Line" and untick it

Comment: Hit Command+, and then use the Search Settings bar at the top to hunt for "Scroll". There is a checkbox to enable/disable scroll past end of file.