# How can I get Eclipse to scroll past the bottom of the document?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, ide, editor

When I **scroll** to the bottom of an open document in the Eclipse **editor**, the last line is at the bottom of the file.  This is a tad annoying when editing code at the **bottom** of the file / screen.

**How can I enable Eclipse to scroll (much like Vim or VS) down far enough that the last line of code reaches the top of the editor window?**

I'm asking for the reverse of this question, in **Eclipse**: [How to make Visual Studio editor stop scrolling past bottom of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747282/how-to-make-visual-studio-editor-stop-scrolling-past-bottom-of-a-file)

Comment: I don't get why is this annoying..

Comment: Its annoying to many people. Editing closer to the center of the window is easier on the eyes, at least in my experience.

Comment: That's basically my problem, eye irritation.  I'm in front of the screen for 8+ hrs a day so it makes a difference.  It's not a massive problem though, more like the difference between using a white-on-black theme vs black-on-white.

Comment: I just tweeted this same complaint before searching and finding your question. I came to Eclipse from Emacs and subtle things like this are disappointing.

Comment: Netbeans is also a great IDE ;-)

Comment: The only bug I could find was https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362540 . Some noise (votes, not comments) might help get attention.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Considering the current implementation of a Scrollbar, this is not possible.
(See [`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ScrollBar.java`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ScrollBar.java.htm))

> At any given moment, a given scroll bar will have a single 'selection' that is considered to be its value, which is constrained to be within the range of values the scroll bar represents (that is, between its *minimum* and *maximum* values).

In the JDT (Java Editor) realm, the range is strongly linked to the number of lines a source file has.
Adding artificial "logical lines" to allows scrolling past the last line would have unintended consequences on many other parts of the JDT, related to displaying informations based on the line number of a source file (like a compilation error red underline).

This is also why there is no soft wrapping in those editors, despite 
a [7-years old bug 35779](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779) (one of the most upvoted).

> Allowing word/soft wrap in the editor while typing is easy but not enough, **a mapping between the model lines and the visual lines must be introduced** to e.g. correctly show annotations.
>   It also introduces various problems that need to be solved, e.g. 'Go to Line': tools like a debugger, compiler etc. will report the model line but a user it will look strange that a different line will be selected than the one entered into the 'Go to Line' dialog

So for now, the [SWT scrollbar example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Demonstratesscrollbars.htm) is still limited by the bottom of the window:

[image: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/ScrollBarExample.PNG]

Comment: Those are extremely lame excuses from the eclipse team. Every decent editors supports those features.

Comment: Totally agree. Very old issue and still no resolution.

Comment: Darn.I assume 4 years later there is still no resolution

Comment: I don't get why they can't fix this. Can't they just plug in a new TextLineControllerFactory? I thought that's how you do it in Java :)

Comment: @OldBadmanGrey .. did he say 3 years ago ... ;] Still nothing. I wonder as well. this doesn't even have to do with the scrollbar! The feature is only visual convenience. In fact: If there are fewer lines than the view is long or lines are collapsed the eclipse text view DOES already show a nice empty space down till the bottom.

Comment: Searching for this Dec 30th 2019, still no solution...  Sublime, Notepad++, NEdit (old stuff :-), and many others do that...