# Eclipse: Scroll down further than file's last line

Tags: eclipse, scroll

I've been searching to no avail for a tweak that would enable Eclipse's editor window to scroll down N lines further below the edited file's last line. Such behavior is supported in:

IntelliJ IDE

VIM (by setting *'set scrolloff=10'* for example, enabling you to scroll 10 lines further below the last line)

Thanks in advance,
amnong

Comment: Sounds like an odd feature to want..

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I get Eclipse to scroll past the bottom of the document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197218/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-scroll-past-the-bottom-of-the-document)

Comment: I'd love it. I'm used to VS and this feature helps you to not have to keep your eyes down at the bottom of the screen. I'd rather work in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Eclipse to scroll past the bottom of the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197218/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-scroll-past-the-bottom-of-the-document)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, you can't. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197218/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-scroll-past-the-bottom-of-the-document).