# Scrolling Past The Bottom In Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, when I'm typing new code, I'm always at the bottom of the file. This means I'm always staring at the bottom of my screen when I type, which is really annoying. Is there a way to configure Android Studio t scroll past the bottom of the file, so the last line can be at the centre of the screen? There's a question about the same topic for Eclipse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197218/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-scroll-past-the-bottom-of-the-document), to which the answer is no. Just wondering if this is possible in Android Studio? I currently just type ~50 new lines at the end of every file I create before coding, but that's just so inelegant.

Comment: I have not seen that sort of feature. Looks like you need a bigger screen!

Comment: @Eenvincible No matter how big my screen is, if this feature wasn't there, I'd still have to put Android Studio in the top half of my screen only. :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

File>Settings>Editor>General

Under Virtual Space section, check "Show virtual space at file bottom"

Or File>Settings and then search "virtual" in the search box to find the setting.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to adjust how much virtual space one can have. Bummer.