# How to make VSCode editor stop scrolling past bottom of a file?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code, editor

In the VSCode **editor** when you pull the **scroll bar** down to the bottom of the file, all you see is a **blank page**, since the text has scrolled up past the **top** of the text editor window. This makes scrolling to the bottom **difficult** because you can't just pull the scroll bar quickly all the way down but have to carefully position the cursor so you can still see your code.

Very similar to [How to make Visual Studio editor stop scrolling past bottom of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747282/how-to-make-visual-studio-editor-stop-scrolling-past-bottom-of-a-file), but comments have pointed out that question/answer is for Visual Studio.  This answer is for VSCode on the macOS and Windows.

Comment: So you've seen a question for visual studio with correct vscode answer (30+ upvotes) and decided to copy it instead of adding vscode tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Visual Studio editor stop scrolling past bottom of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747282/how-to-make-visual-studio-editor-stop-scrolling-past-bottom-of-a-file)

Comment: The wrong answer is marked accepted, so I wanted to be able to find it again.  Just trying to help people find an answer that was helpful to me.  If you disagree, I'll remove the Q/A.

Comment: Set this in your vscode config:  `"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false`
Use Cmd-comma to access config.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible for terminal. I always find it hard to keep my typing at the bottom of the screen in terminal and I do not wish to use the clear command.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

The correct answer is seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588828/1189470

> There is a configuration option provided in VSCode for the functionality you specified. To enable it, go to File -> Preferences -> user settings
>
> On the right side of the editor in settings.json paste the below line at the bottom (before closing bracket), save and close.
>
> `"editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": false`
>
> This will prevent the editor from scrolling beyond the last line.

Answer (score 44):

This is now exposed as a simple checkbox labeled "Editor: Scroll Beyond Last Line" in File/Apple -> Preferences.

Answer (score 23):

If just for readability you would like some space at the bottom of the file - a configurable amount - try this setting as of v1.43:

`editor.padding.bottom`   in pixels

> Editor> Padding: Bottom
>
> Controls the amount of space between the bottom edge of the editor and
>   the last line.

and/or

`editor.padding.top`  // but this isn't *sticky* in the sense that you can scroll right past the padding top and it is gone.  It doesn't stay.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, because I want to scroll past the bottom, but not a full page/screenful (I've set editor.padding.bottom to 400).

Comment: You also need `Editor: Scroll Beyond Last Line` disabled

Comment: It sounds like a good option, but is useless for me, because my 5K external display needs much more pixels than my laptop display. This option is not adaptive to screen resolution or windows resolution. Would be cool if it would be implemented like in Xcode with adaptive values for the overscroll.