# How to scroll past the top of a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently when viewing a file, the content sticks to the top. When you have a tall monitor setup, viewing content at the top of the screen is not that great.

Is there a way to scroll past the top of a file? Like you currently can [the bottom of a file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9XbQ.png)

***The not so great workaround:*** adding a lot of empty lines at the start of the document. My case being 70 lines of nothing to center the top content.

***Update:*** After looking around a little myself in the `settings.json`, there appears to already be support for adding empty lines above the top line. However it does not function the same as when scrolling past last line, which makes it still a *Not so great workaround:*
`"editor.padding.top":`.

Has a limit of 1000, barely making it across half my screen **(Mileage may vary)*. But I suppose it is still better then sharing files with many empty lines to others.

Comment: Looks like it has been proposed before, but it was never implemented due to low interest from the community, see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85268

Comment: why not use half of your monitor, if looking at the top of your monitor is uncomfortable do something to the placement of the monitor

Comment: @rioV8 for multiple reasons. I really like having overview over what I am working on. Sure I could move my monitor to a widescreen setup but that kind of defeats the purpose of a tall monitor setup- having overview of your document. Adding empty lines at the top of the screen is much less of a hassle. But it would be preferred if it could take use of a feature it already uses at the bottom of the document.

Comment: I consider scrolling past the bottom of the file a bug that needs to be fixed, not a feature, it is using the scrollbar incorrectly

Comment: @rioV8 it is a feature. and if you don't like it- Disable it yourself https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588828/1189470

Comment: if it is feature and they don't have a similar setting for the top make an issue on the repo